# Storage - Custom Tree Implementation

Tags: storage

The requirement to utilise a binary merkle tree and sparse merkle tree in a runtime module has recently arisen.  The runtime will need to be able to fetch data and witnesses from the trees.  I have been exploring the best way to implement this by utilising the frameworks provided by substrate.  I watched the following talk given by Shawn Tabrizi which was very insightful and provided a deep dive into substrates storage capabilities https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKKOL20FdII&ab_channel=ParityTech.  Shawn mentions that substrate supports custom tree structures which can be embedded into the global patricia trie as child objects.  Are there any resources that cover custom implementations or ideally some examples?  I also want to understand how this will work with cumulus / parachains.  I assume the implementation need to be compatible with the patterns cumulus uses to construct PoV blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer: If any of the following is wrong, [cheme](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/users/225/cheme) or [shawn](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/users/28/shawn-tabrizi) are probably the best to correct me here. Also, if there is already work being done on this, please comment and correct me.**

The short answer is: unfortunately NO.

The current logic does not allow any non-Patricia-Trie logic as child storage and extending this logic needs changes in some core-substrate code. So it is non-trivial to use a binary merkle tree in child-storage, unless you want to store the whole tree as one byte-blob.

## The problem

1. the low-level API of the storage does not support non-Patricia-Trie logic
2. there is currently no high-level API for child-storage in FRAME (Think of like `StorageMap`, etc. that take care of key-generation)

Of course, the low-level API's design will affect the high-level API's design possibilities. As I thought about this one key question to answer here is: *Does Parity want to allow storage logic under a child-node to be developed independently of substrate?* Why I think this is important will hopefully be clear at the end.

## Possible Solution: *high-level API*

I will start with the high-level API as I think this is the crucial part for teams building on Substrate and it will define the requirements for the low-level API.

### Non-Substrate Datastructures supported

If non-Substrate code logic is supported a possible solution could look something like:

```rust
pub struct ChildStorage<
    Prefix: StorageInstance,
    ChildStorage: CustomStorage,
>(core::marker::PhantomData<(Prefix, ChildStorage)>);

pub trait CustomStorage {
   /// Called when the writing iteration trough the trie reaches
   /// the child-tree root
   fn write(db: &HashDB key: &[u8], value: &[u8]);

   /// Called when the reading iteration trough the trie reaches
   /// the child-tree root
   fn read(db: &HashDB, key: &[u8], value: &[u8])
}
```

and the storage object in a pallet could look something like

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type Binary<T: Config> = ChildStorage<
        _,
        BMerkleTree<Twox64Concat, T::AccountId, T::Balance>,
    >;
```

where `BMerkleTree<Hasher, Key, Value>` takes a hasher, a key and a value that is stored in the leaves.
This approach would allow teams to build their own data structures. The datastructure implementation must then take care of calling `frame_support::storage::child::*` methods that in the end will trigger the `CustomStorage` methods.

BUT

- `ChildInfo` must be adapted and carry the `CustomStorage` object over the FFI of `sp-io`
- exposes `HashDb`

### Only Substrate Datastructures supported

This case is probably "easier" as Parity could provide types like `BMerkleTree` just like the `StorageMap` type and implement specific read- and write-logic after reaching the last trie-node.

## Possible Solution: *low-level API*

The low-level API from my understanding would need some kind of proxy around the `HashDb` (e.g. [`KeyspacedDB`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/367dab0d4bd7fd7b6c222dd15c753169c057dd42/primitives/trie/src/lib.rs#L409-L411). The proxy must take care of checking when the child-root is reached and the logic is leaving the patricia-trie. If this is the case it can forward to `CustomStorage` then.

Also, this would need changes to [`child_storage_root`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/367dab0d4bd7fd7b6c222dd15c753169c057dd42/primitives/state-machine/src/trie_backend_essence.rs#L495-L546) and `sp_io::ChildStorage`.

Anyways, I probably missed a few important things and misunderstand some logic, but maybe this helps for understanding, creating a PR or so.

## Resources

- [Reading low-level](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/367dab0d4bd7fd7b6c222dd15c753169c057dd42/primitives/state-machine/src/trie_backend_essence.rs#L222-L237)
- [Writing low-level](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/367dab0d4bd7fd7b6c222dd15c753169c057dd42/primitives/state-machine/src/trie_backend_essence.rs#L495-L540)

Comment: I think in an ideal world non-substrate data structure support would be best and aligns with the philosophy of the substrate framework in terms of providing developers maximum flexibility.  However I wonder how complex it will be to design a solution of generic interfaces that allow for the declaration of arbitrary storage structures?  Has there been many requests for similar solutions?  only substrate data structure support seems like a reasonable middle ground.  Allow teams to contribute custom data structures to the core substrate framework.  Thanks for the references I will take a look!

Comment: Whats the best way to advance this discussion?  I would be happy to take a stab at the development work but think it be best to align with core developers to ensure we align in terms of design to improve changes of PR acceptance.

Comment: Probably create an issue at substrate repo. Describe your idea and get feedback from Cheme and bkchr.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, sp-io crate provide low level API for implementing storage. So you can build a custom trie and use sp-io to embed it as child trie.